# Using JFileChooser to set values JTextField

Tags: java, user-interface, jtextfield, jfilechooser

I'm learning Java and I'm trying to load some numbers that are inside a .txt file. These numbers need to appear in Text Fields inside my GUI. I've done a lot of research in google but I cant get it to work. Any hints?

```
//TEXT FIELDS
    this.Vx = new JTextField();
    this.Vx.setBounds(120, 20, 100, 30);
    this.add(Vx);
    JLabel etiVx = new JLabel("Vx");
    etiVx.setBounds(90, 20, 90, 40);
    this.add(etiVx);

    this.Vy = new JTextField();
    this.Vy.setBounds(120, 60, 100, 30);
    this.add(Vy);
    JLabel etiVy = new JLabel("Vy");
    etiVy.setBounds(90,60,100,30);
    this.add(etiVy);

//BOTTON TO OPEN .TXT
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    JFileChooser abrir = new JFileChooser();
    if(e.getSource()==this.abrir){
        int returnVal = abrir.showOpenDialog(PanelControl.this);
        if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION);
        File file = abrir.getSelectedFile();

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Abierto");
        try{
            BufferedReader eleccion = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String linea = eleccion.readLine();
            while((linea=eleccion.readLine())!=null){
                Vx.setText(file);
                linea = eleccion.readLine();
            }
        }
        catch(IOException f){
            System.out.println(f);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What is this,

```
           while(eleccion!=null){
                Vx.setText(file);//how can you set a file handler to a TextField
                linea = eleccion.readLine();
            }
```

use,

```
               while((linea=eleccion.readLine())!=null){
                    Vx.setText(linea);

                }
```

If you need to show all the Text in your file it's better to use JTextArea and append all the lines to it that you read from the file.